# Angular charts reloading when closing developer tools

Tags: angularjs, developer-tools, angular-chart

On a page that i'm working on, I use angular charts.

But I noticed that every time I open developer tools (F12)(tested in Chrome & Firefox) and then close it, when i'm closing the developer tools, the charts reload.
Anyone has an idea on why does it happen?

Comment: May be to fit to the new screen size.

Comment: Maybe @Mahesh Sapkal... but the actual size of the screen doesn't really change. I found an online example on git where it also happens: [link]http://chinmaymk.github.io/angular-charts/

Comment: Yes the actual screen size changes, try re-sizing the browser, the charts will re-render.

Comment: Yes I see now. You're rightת thank you. BTW when I open developer tools the tools screen doesnt

Comment: Yes I see now. You're right, thank you. BTW, when I open developer tools, the dev tools window doesn't take space from the web page itself, it opens on top of it.